# What is meant by square free polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, definition

I've tried to read the Wikipedia page on the matter but I can't seem to get my head over it. Can you help me please? It would be nice to see some examples too.

Comment: Which Wikipedia page?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_factorization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as for natural numbers: For a polynomial to be square free, it shouldn't have a (non-unit) factor that's a square. For instance, $x^3-5x^2$ has $x^2$ as a factor, and $x^2$ is a square, so the polynomial is therefore *not* square free.

Note that units are excluded, though. For instance, every real polynomial can be said to have $4 = 2^2$ as a factor, because $f(x) = 4\cdot(\frac14f(x))$. The term "square free" would therefore be very uninteresting if we didn't exclude units.

Comment: Can you please give another example ? And does it depend on the Field we're in ? if its Z3 ( Z modular 3).. does it change ?

Comment: this might help:  Mathematics and Algorithms for Computer Algebra, 1992 Dr Francis J. Wright https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/282/F%20Wright%20notes/week6.pdf